# Google API--Needed, But Issues

Tags: javascript

I'm working on an application in which users will be able to search for an image, and click it to select it as say, their site avatar, using a Google API.

Now, let me just say that I have not even started this yet.

1. Where is the latest Google API (the one I saw was deprecated)
2. How can I keep it from using up CPU (because the deprecated one gave me a CPU Limit Exceeded error...Maybe why it's deprecated?)

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Have you looked at [Google Custom Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview)?